# How to check records already exist in database when u save new record?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I want to add the new records in table if proudct_id and plan_id is already exist in same row then the error occur otherwise it save the record. I have written following lines of code but no success, if there is any help so please, thanks. I am doing it in cakephp

```
    function admin_product_plan_add(){

           $exists    =    $this->ProductPlan->find('all');
           $this->set('exists',$exists);
           foreach ($exists as $exists){
           $plan_id = $exists['ProductPlan']['plan_id'];
           $product_id = $exists['ProductPlan']['product_id'];


           }

     $conditions = array('ProductPlan.product_id' => $plan_id,   'ProductPlan.plan_id' => $product_id);
     $data = $this->ProductPlan->find('all' , array('conditions'=>$conditions));
    if (isset($data) && !empty($data))
    {        
        echo '<p>User have already add this product plan!</p>';
    }else{
        if ($this->ProductPlan->save($this->data)){

            $this->Session->setFlash('You have successfully add the product plan');  
            $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'productplans','action' => 'admin_product_plan_list'));

        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [hasAny()](http://api.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelhasAny)

something like:

```
public function admin_product_plan_add(){
    if($this->ProductPlan->hasAny(array("product_id" => $this->data['ProductPlan']['product_id'],'plan_id' => $this->data['ProductPlan']['plan_id']))){
        // USER ALREADY HAVE THIS PRODUCTPLAN
    } else {
        //CREATE NEW PRODUCTPLAN
    }
}
```

or something like that.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks sir :), it working, the people who downvoted this question didn't know about hasany().

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use a uniq index over these two rows. So when someone tries do add another row with the same data on these two rows, mysql throws an error and the data is not inserted.